# How to use 'create_shared_zip' in cx_Freeze 5.x?

Tags: python, cx-freeze, enthought

I'm building my setup file for a GUI project which uses Enthought (mayavi) and I'm having some trouble, I did some research and I read I need to set `'create_shared_zip': False` for Enthought modules to run properly. It was possible to set this option on versions 4.x but apparently it is no longer available as of versions 5.x or at least it doesn't appear in the documentation, perhaps now they changed the name for how to invoke this option, but I don't know.

I can't use cx_Freeze versions 4.x because my application is on python 3.5.